# How to print dynamic content in Django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am new to python and  django, Ian using paramiko module to get server cpu utilisation and I want to render that output  in my html template. I can print output for a single server in html .

But I am not able to print multiple servers output in html template.

Example:-
I have 100 servers I want to get all the servers cpu utilisation once I logind in my webpage.

I am using CSV file with hostname and IP.

In my views.py i am using for looop to read ips in CSV file . By using paramiko module I am getting output .

I am using below request.

Views.py

For loop

```
return render(request, 'personal/welcome.html', {'host':[hostname],'cpu':[cpu]} )
```

In my html template

```
{{host}} {{cpu}}
```

but I am able to print only last sever output which is last in CSV file.

Please tell me is there any other way to print all servers output or can I save all server output in text file. and print it on same webpage.

-----views.py

```
if user.is_active:
# If the account is valid and active, we can log the user in.
# We'll send the user back to the homepage.
with open('E:\ips.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    print(readCSV)

    for row in readCSV:
        a = row[1]
        b = row[0]
        ip = a
        host=b
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
        ssh_client.connect(ip, username='username', password='password)
        output = ""
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("uname")
        uname = stdout.readlines()
        ssh_client.close()
        for line in uname:
            output = output + line
            if output != "":
                status="online"
            else:
                status="offline"
    login(request, user)
    return render(request,'personal/welcome.html',{'status':[status])
```

------welcome.html

```
  <i></i> HOSTNAME &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; IP_ADDR &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;LIVE_STATUS &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RAM_FREE(GB)

                                  </address>
                              </li>
                          </ol>
                            {% block content %}
                            {% for status in status %}
                              <I></I>{{status}}
                           {% endfor %}
                           % endblock %}
                            <!--<div id="morris-area-chart"></div> -->
```

Comment: You need to post more details of the view and template. Why aren't you loading your CSV into a single list and passing that to the template, and iterating it there?

Comment: Is your intention to connect to 100 servers using paramiko during every django request to a page? That might take a lot of time, I'd rather use a background worker for this (cron or celery).

Comment: Hello Daniel, Please find part of views.py and html template

Comment: Hi kos,thanks for reply actually i want to use SSH protocol to test these servers for load and sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the fairly fundamental concept that in order to collect multiple values, you need to use some sort of container such as a list. I don't really understand what you're trying to do in that code, but it seems you want a list of statuses. So, something like:

```
statuses = []
for row in readCSV:
   ...
   if output != "":
       statuses.append("online")
   else:
       statuses.append("offline")
return render(request,'personal/welcome.html',{'statuses': statuses)
```

and in the template:

```
{% for status in statuses %}
  <i>{{status}}</i>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel,

Yes I forgot about list and I am trying to do is to collect multiple status from each server and need to print on html page output like
Server1 status1 status2 status3
Server2 status1 status2 status3
Actually I am trying to achieve that.